# Reverse string in exercism test environment

Tags: javascript, jasmine

I'm trying to complete an exercism test exercise so that it passes tests in the jasmine testing environment. I managed the first 3 exercises, but I can't understand what I'm doing wrong here.

NB: I do understand I don't have a complete solution for the exercise and I don't want people to show me - I want to figure it out myself, but I'm stumped as to why it doesn't pass the first test? Quite possibly I haven't understood jasmine. This exercise provides the spec.js but requires you to set up the js file yourself.

MY CODE

```
var reverseString = function (input) {
  this.value = input;
};

reverseString.prototype.isreverseString = function () {
  if (this.value == '' || this.value == undefined) {
    return '';
  } else {
    return this.value.split('').reverse().join('');
  }
};

module.exports = reverseString;
```

FIRST TEST

```
var reverseString = require('./reverse-string');

describe('ReverseString', function () {
  it('empty string', function () {
    var expected = '';
    var actual = reverseString('');
    expect(actual).toEqual(expected);
  });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like the spec is expecting the export from `reverse-string.js` (locally called `reverseString`) to be a normal function, but you're trying to define it as a class instead (to be invoked with `new`).

Something along these lines should work better:

```
var reverseString = function (input) {
  if (input == '' || input == undefined) {
    return '';
  } else {
    return input.split('').reverse().join('');
  }
};

module.exports = reverseString;
```